# How to get JobKey / JobDetail of Quartz Job

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm having trouble to understand how I can get the details of a job with Quartz version 2.3.2.

Until now, we used Quartz v1.0.x for jobs and I have to upgrade it to the latest version.

This is how we used to get the details of a job:

```
JobDetail job = scheduler.GetJobDetail(task.Name, groupName);
```

With version 2.3.2, the method `GetJobDetail()` doesn't have a constructor that takes 2 parameter anymore... instead, it takes a `JobKey` parameter.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get a single JobKey.
What I tried is the following:

```
string groupName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(task.GroupNameExtension) ? task.GroupNameExtension : task.GroupName;
var jobkeys = quartzScheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(groupName));
var jobkey = jobkeys.Single(x => x.Name == task.Name);
var jobDetail = quartzScheduler.GetJobDetail(jobkey);
```

- Is this the correct way to implement it / get the jobKey? (will there always be only one jobkey on the line `var jobkey = jobkey.Single(...)`?
- Is there really no way to get a JobDetail without getting **all** the JobKeys first?
- Is this the way Quartz wants us to get the JobDetail or is there a better / simpler way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create a new job key (which is just a fancy storage for a job name and a group name)

```
new JobKey("jobName", "jobGroupName");
```

As long as your job name and job group name is the same with which you created your job, you will be able to get your job detail.

```
var jobDetail = quartzScheduler.GetJobDetail(new JobKey("jobName", "jobGroupName"));
```

personnally, i implement a static method in my job class to centralise the job key creation so i don't have many litterals all over the place :

```
public static JobKey GetJobKey(EntityServer server)
{
    return new JobKey("AutoRestart" + server.Id, "AutoRestart");
}
```

Note that it is also true for the triggerKey

```
public static TriggerKey GetTriggerKey(EntityServer server)
{
    return new TriggerKey("AutoRestart" + server.Id, "AutoRestart");
}
```